# Recursion vs apply in Common Lisp?

Tags: recursion, common-lisp, apply

When I am reading code for learning purposes, I often see functions like this:

```lisp
(defun min-list (lst)
  (cond ((endp (rest lst)) (first lst))
    (t
     (min (first lst) (min-list (rest lst))))))
```

If I were writing this function in my project, I would have written it with `apply`.

```lisp
(defun min-list2 (lst)
  (cond ((endp (rest lst)) (first lst))
    (t
     (apply #'min lst))))))
```

When I test these two variations with `time`, they seem to perform the same.

Does it matter?

Comment: summary: neither recursion nor apply. See the answer from Svante.

Comment: Note that even in your second example, there's no need to check the `(end (rest lst))` case -- [min](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_max_m.htm) requires at least one argument, so `(min 3)` or `(apply 'min '(3))` are fine. However, since it requires at least one, you don't want to apply it to an empty list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They use different styles with different limitations.

The recursion variant, as it is written there, is limited by the space for the stack (you get a stack overflow at some point if the list is too long).  It is possible to rewrite it to be tail recursive, which in most CL implementations will be optimized to more-or-less a loop that doesn't grow the stack, but that's not guaranteed for portable code.

The `apply` variant is limited by [`call-arguments-limit`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_call_a.htm#call-arguments-limit), which is only guaranteed to be at least 50 by the standard, although most implementations have it much higher.  It is usually better to explicitly use `reduce` instead.

Another, also idiomatic, solution is direct looping using `loop`, `do`, or some library such as `iterate` or `for`, and these are usually the most performant (in situations where that matters).

Comment: Where do I go to discover things like `call-arguments-limit`. I haven't seen this anywhere before?

Comment: `It is possible to rewrite it to be tail recursive` - isnt min-list already tail recursive?

Comment: I added a link to a CLHS instance for call-arguments-limit.

Comment: Tail recursive would mean that the result of the recursive call _is_ already the result of the function.  However, in the way it is written there now, the result of the inner `min-list` is further processed by `min`.  A tail recursive version could be `(defun min-list (list) (if (endp (rest list)) (first list) (min-list (cons (min (first list) (second list)) (nthcdr 2 list)))))`.

Comment: The other idiomatic (from a functional programming POV, I guess, moreso than loop at least) solution is to use `reduce`, which is exactly doing what is done here with `min`. The result here would be `(reduce #'min list)`, both clearer and shorter than their loop/do counterparts, especially when taking into account that `min` is a special case for `loop` which has a builtin `:minimize` clause for it with no equivalent for e.g. `*` ...

Comment: I do not share the view that `loop` is somehow not _purely functional_.  It is a declarative mechanism to set up a possibly quite complicated reduce operation that allows many optimizations under the hood.  Additionally, being idiomatic in Common Lisp encompasses more than just _purely functional_.